# Don't give solutions a name

Tags: exsheets

I am using the `exsheet` package and want the solutions to appear directly after the question, without a title or a number.

```
\usepackage{exsheets}
\newcommand{\newquestion}[3]{
    \begin{question}[name=Question, subtitle=#1]
        #2
    \end{question}
    \begin{solution}[name=, print=true]
        #3
    \end{solution}
}
```

However, this prints out a number for each solution. 
For instance, the output of `\newquestion{My question}{Is this a question?}{Yes}` looks like

```
Question 1: My question
  Is this a question?
1:
  Yes
```

whereas I would like something like

```
Question 1: My question
  Is this a question?

  Yes
```

I looked at the options [in the documentation](http://mirrors.standaloneinstaller.com/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/exsheets/exsheets_en.pdf#page=12), but haven't found how to do this.

Comment: BTW: `exsheets` is not developped any more. The successor package is `xsim`

Answer (score 4):

Use the `empty` headings instance for solutions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{exsheets}

\SetupExSheets{
  solution/print = true ,
  question/name = Question ,
  headings = block-subtitle ,
  solution/headings = empty
}

\begin{document}

\begin{question}[subtitle=topic]
  My question
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
  The solution
\end{solution}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In the `solution` environment, the `headings` option can be added: `\begin{solution}[print=true, headings=empty] #3 \end{solution}`